# Show UITextField keyboard on firstResponder even when userInteractionEnabled = NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a UITextField that is first responder. I want to show keyboard when entering the view but I want to do that the user will not be able to edit it and the cursor will be hidden all time as well.

When you click on a keyboard letter, it will be written in the UITextField, but the user will not be able to edit nothing there, even not to copy.

Thanks!

Comment: I think there must be a better solution to your problem than this approach. Just spitballing here, but maybe have a UITextField that is `hidden` that you call `becomeFirstResponder` on, and then in its delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` you could take the text and add it to a `UITextView` or `UITextField` with `userInteractionEnabled = NO`.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean here..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, per my comment, my solution is to have a surrogate `UITextField` that has its `hidden` property set to `YES`. What I do is add that hidden text field to the view, and call `becomeFirstResponder` on it. The user has no idea this text field exists. In the delegate callback from the text field, I take the text the user typed in and add it to a `UITextView` (though you could add the text to whatever you wanted, like a `UITextField` like in your question). I turn off `userInteractionEnabled` for the visible text view. This creates the effect you desire.

I created a sample project that I uploaded to Github. (If you aren't familiar with it, just click the zip button to download it, unzip it, and open the .xcodeproj file). https://github.com/MaxGabriel/HiddenTextField

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much for the solution and of course for the code itself man, it is really amazing what you did here! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer: Try this:

```
1. [txtField becomeFirstResponder]; 
2. txtField.enabled = NO; 
3. when some press on keyboard, then txtField.enabled = YES;
```

Check this out : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKV5csbueHA

Comment: Property 'editable' not found on object of type 'UITextField', Why is that?

Comment: It's working, you can't  edit the UITextField, but the keyboard disappears.. how can I do that the keyboard will stay visible and also that I can click and edit the UITextField through it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `UISearchBar` property in my `viewController`. And I did it like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This should work the same for a `UITextField`.

As for disabling editing, use:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return NO;
}
```

You should have set your viewController to be the delegate of `UITextField`.

Comment: Thats ok, but it's not what I'm asking for. He's already set as first responder, but I want it to be first responder, the keyboard will apeears, stay there but the UITextField will be set to editable = NO

Comment: Hah.. Thats a very weird behavior you are looking for. :\